# Can I reuse boost::ssl::stream?

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, boost-asio

Suppose I use a `boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>`:

```
asio::ssl::stream<asio::ip::tcp::socket> s;
asio::connect(s.lowest_layer(), endpointIterator);
s.handshake(asio::ssl::stream_base::client);
```

And so on. Then for whatever reason the connection fails, or even I disconnect. Is it possible to reuse it for future connections, or do I have to create a new object for each connection? I.e. wrap the stream, something like this:

```
class BetterSslConnection
{
public:
    BetterSslConnection() : mSocket(new asio::ssl::stream<asio::ip::tcp::socket>()) 
    {
    }

    ~BetterSslConnection()
    {
        if (mSocket)
        {
            mSocket->shutdown();
            mSocket->lowest_layer().close();
        }
    }

    void connect(... endpointIterator)
    {
        if (mSocket)
        {
            mSocket->shutdown();
            mSocket->lowest_layer().close();
        }
        mSocket.reset(new asio::ssl::stream<asio::ip::tcp::socket>());

        asio::connect(mSocket->lowest_layer(), endpointIterator);
        mSocket->handshake(asio::ssl::stream_base::client);
        // and so on.
    }

private:
    unique_ptr<asio::ssl::stream<asio::ip::tcp::socket>> mSocket;

};
```

class BetterSslConnection
{